# Redshift External PostgreSQL Schema data type error numeric vs numeric(x,y)

Tags: amazon-redshift

So I created an external schemas in redshift using the prescribed syntax:

```sql
create external schema if not exists external_psql_db
from POSTGRES
DATABASE 'production' SCHEMA 'public'
URI 'xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx'
SECRET_ARN 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxx:secret:xxx/xxx'
;
```

However I cannot query or even join certain tables that have numeric columns.

Redshift lists a column of a table as data type `numeric` whereas when I check it connected to PSQL directly I get `numeric(65,2)`.

When I try to query the table (or join it into another query) I get this error in DBeaver (and DBT):

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   precision <= 38 - precision=65, 38=38. 
  query:     0
  location:  pg_utils.cpp:4716
  process:   padbmaster [pid=14415]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I cannot see anything in the `create external schema` documentation for redshift to specify anything around column data types, redshift is supposed to handle that. How do I query those tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift's maximum precision on numeric types is 38, thats why the error is failing the assertion. Your precision is 65, which is not less than or equal to 38.

Try explicitly casting down to 38 precision, or try querying from another field with a precision <= 38 and see if that works.

Relevent docs:

```
precision
The total number of significant digits in the whole value: the number of digits on both sides of the decimal point. For example, the number 48.2891 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4. The default precision, if not specified, is 18. The maximum precision is 38.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html#r_Numeric_types201-decimal-or-numeric-type

Comment: Is it possible to change the precision in redshift or have it cast it? Modifying the schema of the external PSQL db is not necessarily an option. Redshift throws this assert error even when I'm not selecting the numeric columns in question.

Comment: I think if you're hooking up to RDS and letting it use the catalog, it will infer all the data types, so maybe not an option. Something you may be able to do as a workaround is either make a view in RDS where you cast the columns explicitly in the view def, or try making an external table with the external schema with the specific column definitions. Again, for the 2nd option that might not be possible if the external schema is just reading everything from a data catalog in RDS.

Comment: We ended up having to do a DB migration on the RDS to alter the column precision to the redshift maximum (65 is way overkill anyways).